# Problems building with ImageResizer FastScaling in release mode

Tags: visual-studio, imageresizer

I am having problems getting my project to build in Release mode (both locally and externally) after adding FastScaling 64 bit version. I noticed the problem when trying to build the solution with TeamCity. Whilst in debug mode locally it works fine.

The error I am getting is "Could not load file or assembly 'ImageResizer.Plugins.FastScaling' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.".

I am trying to build the solution with VS2015 and the VC++ 2015 redistributable 64bit installed. I have also set the platform target for the project to x64, and checked the "Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects."-box.

The setup looks like this in the proj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion></ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>guid</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>guid</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>ProjectName.Web</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>ProjectName.Web</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
    <UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
    <FileUpgradeFlags></FileUpgradeFlags>
    <UpgradeBackupLocation></UpgradeBackupLocation>
    <OldToolsVersion>12.0</OldToolsVersion>
    <IISExpressSSLPort />
    <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>disabled</IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>
    <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>enabled</IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>
    <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode>false</IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    <MvcProjectUpgradeChecked>true</MvcProjectUpgradeChecked>
    <UseGlobalApplicationHostFile />
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp></NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    <Use64BitIISExpress />
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Any pointers to what I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you're getting 32-bit FastScaling jnstead ofn64-bit or vice versa. Inspect the /bin directory to see which one is actually being copied over.

Comment: Thank your for the tip. 

When checking the dll with dotPeek it says x64, which is what I am trying to target. Is one of the versions recommended over the other? I have a feeling that there is something with the build configuration, but I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions, @nathanael? It would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Create a deployment in a separate directory and make sure that the dll is still correct. It could be picking up the wrong version from somewhere else.